What is the meaning of this 'for' loop in the lock free queue implementation in the book "C++ Concurrency in Action"?
I am reading Anthony Williams's "C++ Concurrency in Action, Second Edition", and I encountered this code:
template<typename T>
class lock_free_queue
{
private:
    void set_new_tail(counted_node_ptr &old_tail,
                      counted_node_ptr const &new_tail)
    {
        node* const current_tail_ptr=old_tail.ptr;
        while(!tail.compare_exchange_weak(old_tail,new_tail) &&
              old_tail.ptr==current_tail_ptr);
        if(old_tail.ptr==current_tail_ptr)
            free_external_counter(old_tail);
        else
            current_tail_ptr->release_ref();
    }
public:
    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<T> new_data(new T(new_value));
        counted_node_ptr new_next;
        new_next.ptr=new node;
        new_next.external_count=1;
        counted_node_ptr old_tail=tail.load();
        for(;;)
        {
            increase_external_count(tail,old_tail);
            T* old_data=nullptr;
            if(old_tail.ptr->data.compare_exchange_strong(
                   old_data,new_data.get()))
            {
                counted_node_ptr old_next={0};
                if(!old_tail.ptr->next.compare_exchange_strong(
                       old_next,new_next))
                {
                    delete new_next.ptr;
                    new_next=old_next;
                }
                set_new_tail(old_tail, new_next);
                new_data.release();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                counted_node_ptr old_next={0};
                if(old_tail.ptr->next.compare_exchange_strong(
                       old_next,new_next))
                {
                    old_next=new_next;
                    new_next.ptr=new node;
                }
                set_new_tail(old_tail, old_next);
            }
        }
    }
};

The remaining part is in GitHub, which is from listing_7.19.cpp to listing_7.22.cpp.
Here I encounter some problems, that I can't understand this part:
for(;;)
        {
            increase_external_count(tail,old_tail);
            T* old_data=nullptr;
            if(old_tail.ptr->data.compare_exchange_strong(
                   old_data,new_data.get()))
            {
                counted_node_ptr old_next={0};
                if(!old_tail.ptr->next.compare_exchange_strong(
                       old_next,new_next))
                {
                    delete new_next.ptr;
                    new_next=old_next;
                }
                set_new_tail(old_tail, new_next);
                new_data.release();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                counted_node_ptr old_next={0};
                if(old_tail.ptr->next.compare_exchange_strong(
                       old_next,new_next))
                {
                    old_next=new_next;
                    new_next.ptr=new node;
                }
                set_new_tail(old_tail, old_next);
            }
        }

First, I think old_tail is something not null, why does it compare this to old_data (which is a nullptr) in this statement?

if(old_tail.ptr->data.compare_exchange_strong(
                   old_data,new_data.get()))


And, what is the above for loop actually doing?
I completely can't understand this.

One question per question, please!  Are you asking what exactly compare_exchange_strong does?  Or are you asking us to explain the entire for(;;) loop?

I can't understand why we set the expected value as nullptr in T* old_data=nullptr;
if(old_tail.ptr->data.compare_exchange_strong(
old_data,new_data.get())) @DrewDormann

If the question is why put this:
T* old_data=nullptr;
if(old_tail.ptr->data.compare_exchange_strong(old_data,new_data.get()))
          //...

Rather than say this:
if(old_tail.ptr->data.compare_exchange_strong(nullptr,new_data.get()))
         //...

That's because compare_exchange_strong() returns the value at the point of compare in the first argument so it requires a modifiable l-value (a reference).
In the specimen code the value returned isn't used. But there isn't a version of the member that accepts a constant.
If the question is "what is the for(;;) loop doing?"
The answer is using compare_exchange_strong() to try and be the thread that either populates data in the tail or adds a new tail to populate.
The logic is lockless (if the relevant atomic operations are lockless on the target platform - not guaranteed) but the downside is that may require several attempts (iterations) for a thread to be 'the winner' and under high load there's a risk of 'live lock' behaviour because it's not guaranteed when a given thread will succeed.
Lock-free implementations sound attractive but sometimes come with downsides that can be worse than locking and completing the work in a single pass.
Of course introducing a lock in the form of a std::mutex doesn't guarantee any fairness and (again) high load scenarios may result in live-lock behaviours. But the point remains that the implementation shown isn't necessarily a silver bullet.
This code demonstrates the first point:
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

int main() {
    int value1{1};
    int value2{2};
    std::atomic<int *> x(&value1);
    int * e=nullptr;
    
    auto r{x.compare_exchange_strong(e,&value2)};
    
    std::cout<<r<<' '<<e<<' '<<&value1<<'\n';
    
    return 0;
}
   

Typical Output:
0 0x7ffe378b5340 0x7ffe378b5340

Notice that the address returned for e is the address of value1.

I did not look at the GitHub code, but presumably ld_tail.ptr->data is an std::atomic, in which case compare_exchange_strong() takes a reference to a variable in its 1st parameter, and will update that variable with the result of the comparison.

Atomically compares the [object representation (until C++20)] [value representation (since C++20)] of *this with that of expected. If those are bitwise-equal, replaces the former with desired (performs read-modify-write operation). Otherwise, loads the actual value stored in *this into expected (performs load operation).

So, initializing the old_data variable with nullptr first means the author is checking whether the atomic data has a value of nullptr or not. If it does, then data will be updated with the value of the 2nd parameter (new_data).
The for loop is re-trying that update until it actually happens.
